# Deserialize an Avro file with C#

Tags: c#, azure, hadoop, avro

I can't find a way to deserialize an Apache Avro file with C#. The Avro file is a file generated by the [Archive feature](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-archive-overview/) in Microsoft Azure Event Hubs.

With Java I can use [Avro Tools](http://www-us.apache.org/dist/avro/avro-1.8.1/java/avro-tools-1.8.1.jar) from Apache to convert the file to JSON:

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.8.1.jar tojson --pretty inputfile > output.json
```

Using NuGet package **Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro** I am able to extract `SequenceNumber`, `Offset` and `EnqueuedTimeUtc`, but since I don't know what type to use for `Body` an exception is thrown. I've tried with `Dictionary<string, object>` and other types.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fileName = "...";

    using (Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        using (var reader = AvroContainer.CreateReader<EventData>(stream))
        {
            using (var streamReader = new SequentialReader<EventData>(reader))
            {
                var record = streamReader.Objects.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging")]
public class EventData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "SequenceNumber")]
    public long SequenceNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Offset")]
    public string Offset { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "EnqueuedTimeUtc")]
    public string EnqueuedTimeUtc { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Body")]
    public foo Body { get; set; }

    // More properties...
}
```

The schema looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "EventData",
  "namespace": "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "SequenceNumber",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "Offset",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "EnqueuedTimeUtc",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "SystemProperties",
      "type": {
        "type": "map",
        "values": [ "long", "double", "string", "bytes" ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Properties",
      "type": {
        "type": "map",
        "values": [ "long", "double", "string", "bytes" ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Body",
      "type": [ "null", "bytes" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This may help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993644/reading-event-hub-archive-file-in-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993644/reading-event-hub-archive-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What about snappy coding? Anyone having issues?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to get full data access working using `dynamic`. Here's the code for accessing the raw `body` data, which is stored as an array of bytes. In my case, those bytes contain UTF8-encoded JSON, but of course it depends on how you initially created your `EventData` instances that you published to the Event Hub:

```
using (var reader = AvroContainer.CreateGenericReader(stream))
{
    while (reader.MoveNext())
    {
        foreach (dynamic record in reader.Current.Objects)
        {
            var sequenceNumber = record.SequenceNumber;
            var bodyText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(record.Body);
            Console.WriteLine($"{sequenceNumber}: {bodyText}");
        }
    }
}
```

If someone can post a statically-typed solution, I'll upvote it, but given that the bigger latency in any system will almost certainly be the connection to the Event Hub Archive blobs, I wouldn't worry about parsing performance. :)

Comment: great nice one I want to do similar stuff here is my detail questions any help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462311/how-do-i-read-event-hub-log-data-which-is-capture-in-blob-using-c-sharp

Comment: As a footnote, when Event Hub Capture gives you an "empty" blob (no events received in a given partition during that capture interval) -- such blobs are 508 B in size in my case currently -- then the deserialization fails with a mysterious complaint about a "size" parameter (`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: size'`). The same logic works again as soon as at least one event is present in the capture blob.

Comment: I get Invalid Avro object container in a stream. The header cannot be recognized.

Answer (score 11):

This [Gist](https://gist.github.com/pshrosbree/74c8c4b4744c00cf3d92939952808d1e) shows how to deserialize an event hub capture with C# using Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro2, which has the advantage of being both .NET Framework 4.5 and .NET Standard 1.6 compliant:

```
 var connectionString = "<Azure event hub capture storage account connection string>";
 var containerName = "<Azure event hub capture container name>";
 var blobName = "<Azure event hub capture BLOB name (ends in .avro)>";

 var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
 var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
 var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
 var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
 using (var stream = blob.OpenRead())
 using (var reader = AvroContainer.CreateGenericReader(stream))
     while (reader.MoveNext())
         foreach (dynamic result in reader.Current.Objects)
         {
             var record = new AvroEventData(result);
             record.Dump();
         }

 public struct AvroEventData
 {
     public AvroEventData(dynamic record)
     {
         SequenceNumber = (long) record.SequenceNumber;
         Offset = (string) record.Offset;
         DateTime.TryParse((string) record.EnqueuedTimeUtc, out var enqueuedTimeUtc);
         EnqueuedTimeUtc = enqueuedTimeUtc;
         SystemProperties = (Dictionary<string, object>) record.SystemProperties;
         Properties = (Dictionary<string, object>) record.Properties;
         Body = (byte[]) record.Body;
     }
     public long SequenceNumber { get; set; }
     public string Offset { get; set; }
     public DateTime EnqueuedTimeUtc { get; set; }
     public Dictionary<string, object> SystemProperties { get; set; }
     public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }
     public byte[] Body { get; set; }
 }
```

- NuGet references:

  - Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro2 (1.2.1 works)
  - WindowsAzure.Storage (8.3.0 works)
- Namespaces:

  - Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.Container
  - Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage

Comment: please [avoid "link-only answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259). consider that the link could be broken in future and the answer should be useful also without it.

Comment: great nice one I want to do similar stuff here is my detail questions any help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462311/how-do-i-read-event-hub-log-data-which-is-capture-in-blob-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 10):

I was finally able to get this to work with the Apache C# library / framework.
I was stuck for a while because the Capture feature of the Azure Event Hubs sometimes outputs a file without any message content. 
I may have also had an issue with how the messages were originally serialized into the EventData object.
The code below was for a file saved to disk from a capture blob container.

```
var dataFileReader = DataFileReader<EventData>.OpenReader(file);
foreach (var record in dataFileReader.NextEntries)
{
   // Do work on EventData object
}
```

This also works using the GenericRecord object.

```
var dataFileReader = DataFileReader<GenericRecord>.OpenReader(file);
```

This took some effort to figure out.  However I now agree this Azure Event Hubs Capture feature is a great feature to backup all events. I still feel they should make the format optional like they did with Stream Analytic job output but maybe I will get used to Avro.

Comment: how exactly you have used this code ? DataFileReader is in which nuget?

Comment: @neo One version of the DataFileReader that works with the above code can be found `Confluent.Apache.Avro` nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use https://github.com/AdrianStrugala/AvroConvert

And simply:

```
byte[] avroFileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
var result = AvroConvert.Deserialize<EventData>(avroFileContent);
```

The library itself was meant to be an improvement of dev flow with using Avro format. You don't even need the schema or attributes on your model. (I am a contributor to this library)

Comment: Be aware, the license for AvroConvert does **not** permit the use of it within Commercial projects. Which will make this solution unviable for some.

Answer (score 0):

Your remaining types, I suspect should be defined as:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging")]
[KnownType(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>))]
public class EventData
{
    [DataMember]
    public IDictionary<string, object> SystemProperties { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public byte[] Body { get; set; }
}
```

Even though `Body` is a union of `null` and `bytes`, this maps to a `nullable` `byte[]`.

In C#, arrays are always reference types so can be `null` and the contract fulfilled.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work though: `Could not find any matching known type for 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary\`2[System.String,System.Object]'.`.

Comment: @KristofferJälén Is that exception specifically for the `Body` property?

Comment: No, that exception was for the `SystemProperties` property.

Comment: Try annotating the class with the likes of `[KnownType(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>))]`? Else you may try using the concrete type instead of the interface as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `NullableSchema` attribute to mark the Body as union of bytes and null. This will allow you to use the strongly typed interface.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging")]
public class EventData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "SequenceNumber")]
    public long SequenceNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Offset")]
    public string Offset { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "EnqueuedTimeUtc")]
    public string EnqueuedTimeUtc { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Body")]
    [NullableSchema]
    public foo Body { get; set; }
}
```