# How to deserialize Avro messages in Kafka using C#

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

Hi I am working Confluent kafka. I have consumer which returns generic record. I want to de-serialize it. I dint find any way. I can do manually each field like

```
 object options = ((GenericRecord)response.Message.Value["Product"])["Options"];
```

I found one here

> [Deserialize an Avro file with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846833/deserialize-an-avro-file-with-c-sharp)
>   But how can I convert my schema into stream?
>   I want to know If we can de-serialize into our c# model using any solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. But my schema contains data. Consumer is returning. How can I convert my schema into stream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the [`confluent-dot-net`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/) client, you can use [`AvroDeserializer`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/api/Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes.AvroDeserializer-1.html):

> (async) Avro deserializer. Use this deserializer with `GenericRecord`,
> types generated using the `avrogen.exe` tool or one of the following
> primitive types: `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `boolean`, `string`, `byte[]`.

[Example](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AvroGeneric/Program.cs):

```
var consumeTask = Task.Run(() =>{
  using(var schemaRegistry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(new SchemaRegistryConfig {
    SchemaRegistryUrl = schemaRegistryUrl
  }))
  using(var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder < string, GenericRecord > (new ConsumerConfig {
    BootstrapServers = bootstrapServers,
    GroupId = groupName
  }).SetKeyDeserializer(new AvroDeserializer < string > (schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync()).SetValueDeserializer(new AvroDeserializer < GenericRecord > (schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync()).SetErrorHandler((_, e) =>Console.WriteLine($ "Error: {e.Reason}")).Build()) {
    consumer.Subscribe(topicName);

    try {
      while (true) {
        try {
          var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(cts.Token);

          Console.WriteLine($ "Key: {consumeResult.Message.Key}\nValue: {consumeResult.Value}");
        }
        catch(ConsumeException e) {
          Console.WriteLine($ "Consume error: {e.Error.Reason}");
        }
      }
    }
    catch(OperationCanceledException) {
      // commit final offsets and leave the group.
      consumer.Close();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Assuming I have to use DeserializeAsync(ReadOnlyMemory<Byte>, Boolean, SerializationContext). So what should I sent to parameter ReadOnlyMemory<Byte> and SerializationContext

Comment: Hi Giorgos. Can You tell me what should I pass to DeserializeAsync method?

Comment: You can use `new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(data.ToArray())`

Comment: So data will be of typeConsumeResult<string, GenericRecord>?

Comment: My data returned from consumer is of type ConsumeResult<string, Genericrecord> so what can I pass now?