# How to deserialize the rowkey of a ksql query in c#?

Tags: c#, avro, ksqldb

I would like to display the ROWKEY of a query result. Unfortunately it is not serialized as this is currently not supported in ksql. No problem i could do this by myself. But i dont know how..

So if i do this via rest api:

```
SELECT ROWKEY FROM topic
```

How do i turn this result into something i can actually use in C#?

How is the result (eg: \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001�\b\u0000�\f ) structured? Does it contain the magic byte or something else?

I tried the solutions from here:

[Deserialize an Avro file with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846833/deserialize-an-avro-file-with-c-sharp)

all with different versions of the result byte[] ... eg with the magic byte appended, with removing bytes from the beginning .. replacing the bytes in the beginning to the magic byte etc.

EDIT: iam talking about a programmatic solution with C# and not KSQL Server alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't. KSQL doesn't currently support any keys other than strings. You can't pass through an Avro key from a topic through KSQL and out to a consumer that then deserialises the Avro.

If you need to get the key, then just consume the Kafka topic that underpins the KSQL stream/table using a native consumer and deserialise it from there.

Comment: So KSQL Server is just returning useless data here? There is no way to somehow deserialize this message "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001�\b\u0000�\f" if i know the schema?

Comment: See my answer above :)

Comment: What is the returned string ""\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001�\b\u0000�\f"" actually? Where does it come from?

Comment: It's the Avro data that KSQL is reading from the key of the message, but KSQL uses a String deserialiser hence the weird characters.

Comment: A that makes sense. Is there no way to replace this serializer with a different one/get the raw avro data? Thanks for your answer

Comment: There's work ongoing in KSQL to improve its handling of keys. Check out https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/.

Comment: One last question: Is it possible to serialize the message back into an byte[] and then deserialize it to the original msg?

Comment: I tried some stuff by myself and because avro serializes strings as "num of chars", following the msg, i started to parse the message to byte[] from utf8 encoding, then removing the first byte (the number of chars), then using this as the real bytearray and parsing it to the record. This "kinda" works for everything except for integers. Enums/strings/arrays etc are all parsed correct, but the integer is completely off: could you know why?

Comment: After some more digging, this solution would work if the string serializer could handle all the avro bytes. Sometimes the stringserializer will print "?" or (239,191,189) which means the byte could not be converted to utf-8.